# a question on ActiveRecord query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

in my model, I use the where statement to query the DB table:

```
where(:date=>start_date..end_date)
```

It is obvious that I would like to get all records between `start_date` and `end_date` in the **date** column. The `start_date` and `end_date` are Date type values.

Based on this query, I get the results from the table **BUT not exactly everything**.

The data match the date value of "**end_date**" is **not** return. That's this query exclude the data on end_date, it only get the results from `start_date` to `end_date-1.day`, how to get rid of this? I want to use this query to return the data with **end_date**>=**date**>=**start_date**

Comment: Please search question history

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try: 
`where('date BETWEEN ? AND ?', start_date, end_date)`